# Auto Camera Upload on Windows 10 UWP App

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I would like to add to my app UWP on Windows 10 auto camera upload to the cloud function.

So basically I need [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj571205(v=vs.105).aspx) functionality, which according to other sources was not supported in WP8.1 so I dropped the idea.

Now when Lumia 950 and Windows 10 Mobile is out I would very much liked to add this function to my app, but unfortunately I can't find anything about it on newest Windows Mobile. Maybe you can help?

Answer (score 1):

The page you link to is only about having a specific page for the auto upload settings within an app. It doesn't do the automatic uploading for you.

That list was only in WP8 and is not in Windows10 so you can't be added to a list that doesn't exist.

To do the uploading you should look at the Background Transfer API. Specifically the [BackgroundUploader class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.aspx).
There's even a [sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61). (sample is for Win8.1 but should work with minimal modification.)

**update - based on coments**
I don't know how Dropbox do it (they may have special privileges not available to every developer) but you could create the functionality to upload newly taken photos by having a background task based on a timed event that checks for new files in the [camera roll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.cameraroll.aspx) and uploads any it finds.

Comment: I know, but this background transfer must be triggered automatic on taking a photo and that's the real case

Comment: @Piachu the automatic triggering of uploads of photos is not what the functionality you linked to does. There is no way to do that.

Comment: I thought so too, but for example univerasal dropbox app have function to auto upload photos to dropbox. I want to do just that

Answer (score 0):

this feature is only supported by Silverlight app model, not Universal Windows Platform model.
You might want to use the OneDrive SDK to upload your photo/video to the Cloud https://github.com/onedrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp

Comment: I have an app that uploads files to Google Drive, but I want auto-upload new photos from camera roll

Comment: You can use the same app model using the Google Drive APIs. Here's a great starting point using @pedro-lamas GDrive sample on GitHub

https://github.com/PedroLamas/GDrive

Comment: I saw that, but it's wrong example - my app can already do more than that - and it's WP7 app, without autoupload